# How to loop at existing Excel rows till the last row

Tags: excel, vba

I need to update an Excel sheet table from a SAP GUI table that has a different number of rows each time.
[image: Excel sheet]
Therefore, I need to count the cells in column "A" and set them as in my code.
See below an excerpt of the code.

My code works fine but I think there is an easier way than to write such a code for any number of rows.

```vb
Sub SAP_OpenSessionFromLogon()
Dim SapGui
Dim Applic
Dim connection
Dim session
Dim WSHShell
Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe"
Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Do Until WSHShell.AppActivate("SAP Logon ")
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
Loop
Set WSHShell = Nothing
Set SapGui = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set Applic = SapGui.GetScriptingEngine
Set connection = Applic.OpenConnection("System", True)
Set session = connection.Children(0)
session.findById("wnd[0]").Maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-MANDT").Text = "100"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").Text = "Name"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").Text = "PW"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.SendCommand ("/nZPS_RE008K_NEW")
session.findById("wnd[0]").Maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI_VBUKR").Text = "1200"
Set xclsht = ActiveSheet
Set sht = Nothing
Set wbk = Nothing
Set xcl = Nothing
If Sheets("FORMAT").Cells(6, 1) Like "*IE-12-2007984*" Then
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI_PSPID-LOW").Text = Sheets("Format").Cells(6, 1)
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_VARI").Text = "/NEW 008K"
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
Set myGrid = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell")
Sheets("Format").Cells(6, 3).Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(i, "ZZ_PTREL")
Sheets("Format").Cells(6, 30).Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(i, "CASTKA_ROZPOCTU")
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
If Sheets("FORMAT").Cells(7, 1) Like "*IE-12-2007984*" Then
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI_PSPID-LOW").Text = Sheets("Format").Cells(7, 1)
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_VARI").Text = "/NEW 008K"
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
Set myGrid = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell")
Sheets("Format").Cells(7, 3).Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(i, "ZZ_PTREL")
Sheets("Format").Cells(7, 30).Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(i, "CASTKA_ROZPOCTU")
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
If Sheets("Format").Cells(8, 1) Like "*IE-12-2007984*" Then
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI_PSPID-LOW").Text = Sheets("Format").Cells(8, 1)
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_VARI").Text = "/NEW 008K"
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
Set myGrid = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell")
Sheets("Format").Cells(8, 3).Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(i, "ZZ_PTREL")
Sheets("Format").Cells(8, 30).Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(i, "CASTKA_ROZPOCTU")
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
If Sheets("Format").Cells(9, 1) Like "*IE-12-2007984*" Then
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI_PSPID-LOW").Text = Sheets("Format").Cells(9, 1)
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_VARI").Text = "/NEW 008K"
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
Set myGrid = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell")
Sheets("Format").Cells(9, 3).Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(i, "ZZ_PTREL")
Sheets("Format").Cells(9, 30).Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(i, "CASTKA_ROZPOCTU")
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
If Sheets("Format").Cells(10, 1) Like "*IE-12-2007984*" Then
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI_PSPID-LOW").Text = Sheets("Format").Cells(10, 1)
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_VARI").Text = "/NEW 008K"
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
Set myGrid = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell")
Sheets("Format").Cells(10, 3).Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(i, "ZZ_PTREL")
Sheets("Format").Cells(10, 30).Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(i, "CASTKA_ROZPOCTU")
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
End Sub
```

[image: Explanation]

[image: SAP pcs "B"]

[image: SAP pcs "A"]

Comment: The code could be VBA or VBScript, please clarify. If I understand well, your question is only about VBA, how to avoid repeating the same kind of blocks. Which blocks exactly? You seem to repeat many things, the rows are varying, why not using a variable in `Cells(row,3)` as you did for the SAP GUI `GridView` rows with variable `i`? (although I don't understand why you use `i` a its value seems to be constantly zero (first row).

Comment: I'm going to use this code for excel sheet, as macro. So it' could be VBA. Am I right?

Comment: Basically I need to copy the first number from the table to the transaction (SAP) LAYOUT and update the other cells based on this number.
That's right, many rows are repeated and each differs only in cells.
The variable for GridView (i) completely unnecessarily, that's true, but as I say I don't have much experience with this, what is absolutely simple for you is very difficult for me.

Comment: I still don't understand if your question is about looping at columns or at rows, and if it's about looping at Excel sheet or at SAP GUI table. If it also concerns SAP GUI, maybe you can show a screenshot of SAP GUI screen and the corresponding expected data in Excel sheet (manually set).

Comment: Answer is about looping rows.  I ll add more information about this.

Comment: So informations are  added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test the following:

```
...
Set xcl = Nothing
i = 6
do
 'If Sheets("FORMAT").Cells(i, 1) Like "*IE-12-2007984*" Then
  'End If
  session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI_PSPID-LOW").Text = Sheets("Format").Cells(i, 1)
  session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_VARI").Text = "/NEW 008K"
  session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
  Set myGrid = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell")
  Sheets("Format").Cells(i, 3).Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(0, "ZZ_PTREL")
  Sheets("Format").Cells(i, 30).Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(0, "CASTKA_ROZPOCTU")
  session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
 i = i + 1
 If Sheets("Format").Cells(i, 1).Value = 0 Then Exit Do
Loop
End Sub
```

Ahoj, ScriptMan

Comment: I ll test this and let u know

Comment: Based on the further explanations, I have made changes in my proposed solution.

Comment: So, it's working perfect, I have a lot of questions. Can I ask u somewhere?

Comment: Of course  the other question is whether I can aswer it.

Comment: Why is in your code  I= 6 what does mean? Is that mean that function ll start on the 6 row? Where can I find some rules how to use it? And can u write me on my email adress? mm.bretislav@gmail.com I have more questions.

Comment: Sorry I did not upvote the answer as correct @ScriptMan